# divisibility with phi function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\phi(x)$ denote the number of positive integers less than or equal to $n$ relatively prime to $n$. Characterize all $k$ such that $k \mid (m\phi(k)+1)$ for some positive integer $m$.

---

I've thought about letting $k=p_1^{e_1}\dots p_{a}^{e_a}$ for some prime $p_i$ but the method seems very messy. I am unable to get any other ideas on what to do here.

Comment: Begin with this hint: Note that if $p^2\mid k$ then $p\mid \varphi(k)$

Comment: Ah thanks. I see that this implies $k$ is square free, (all the exponents of primes in its prime factorization is $1$) but i'm still not sure how I can progress past that.

Comment: suggest you find the $k$ up to, say, $50$  that work, meaning $k$   and $\phi(k)$ are relatively prime.  When you have no idea what is happening with number theory questions, examples are best, and small numbers when possible.

Comment: ...and then [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003277) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $k \mid m \,\varphi(k)+1$ for some $m$ is equivalent to the existence of a solution of the equation $$\varphi(m)\, x\equiv -1\pmod m$$

A necessary and sufficient condition for that is that $\varphi(m)$ is coprime with $m$.

Thus $m$ must be squarefree and also, given any two primes $p$ and $q$ dividing $m$ it must happen that $p$ doesn't divide $q-1$.

As Ivan Neretin observed, the sequence of such $m$ is in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003277). There is probably no simpler characterization of this (otherwise, it would be in the OEIS).